# Ruby prevent command injection with open3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, 7zip, popen3, commandinjection

in one of the project I am working with, we were using backtip approach to run system commands.

```
resp = `7z x #{zip_file_path} -p#{password} -o#{output_path}`
```

which works fine. But since it might lead to command injection vulnerability we are planning to use `exec` or `open3`. With `open3` we are facing issue in executing system commands. We referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050109/ruby-exec-command-injection-protection) to resolve command injection.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3("7z", "x", zip_file_path, "-p", password, "-o", output_path)
```

But this leads to below error

```
error = stderr.readlines
# ["\n", "\n", "Command Line Error:\n", "Too short switch:\n", "-o\n"]
```

This works when I include params like this.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3("7z", "x", zip_file_path, "-p#{password}", "-o#{output_path}")
```

But shouldn't we pass arguments separately to avoid command injection? Or Am I doing anything wrong with first version?

Comment: Do you mean “backtick approach” with ` ,  or is "backtip" something else?  :-) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second version (the one that works):

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3("7z", "x", zip_file_path, "-p#{password}", "-o#{output_path}")
```

is perfectly safe. There's no shell involved so there's nothing that will interpret `password` and `output_path` other than `7z` itself.

---

Unfortunately `7z` has a strange way of parsing switches. Normally you'd expect to pass arguments to switches by saying `-p xyz` and `-pxyz` would be a short form of `-p -x -y -z`. When you say:

```
Open3.popen3("7z", "x", zip_file_path, "-p", password, "-o", output_path)
```

that's like saying this in the shell:

```
7z x zip_file_path -p password -o output_path
```

but `7z` doesn't like those spaces, it wants:

```
7z x zip_file_path -ppassword -ooutput_path
```

so you're stuck doing a bit of string interpolation. Even so, there's no shell involved with `Open3` so no injection.

Comment: Just one more clarification. From the doc it seems with `popen3` I need to close the stdin, stdout and stderr stream. Does `capture3` make more sence here?

Comment: Ah yes the good old stutter arguments.

Comment: Yes, I think `capture3` would be a better fit for you. You're not having a conversation with `7z` or feeding it a stream of data, you just want it to unpack an archive and then check its output.